# Is there an easy way to standardize every single column in a table without loops (using R)?

Tags: r, loops, transform, normalize

I need to standardize all except one column in a dataframe, with which I'm using knn. I know that I can do this with loops, but it seems like there might be an easier way, especially since I am working with 200+ columns/factors, which would have to be renamed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would use `scale` to standardize *all* the columns, saving the result to a new data frame (actually you might need a matrix to use `scale` -- I don't remember), then copy the original (unstandardized) copy of the column you want to preserve back to the new data frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes. I assumed you would prefer to identify the variable not to be scaled based on its name rather than identfying it by it's column position. Without a toy example I can only surmise this is exactly what you want.

```
x <- data.frame(replicate(10, rnorm(10)))
names(x) <- letters[1:10]

##let's say you don't want to scale "b"
scalevars <- setdiff(names(x), "b")
x.scaled <- data.frame(sapply(x[,scalevars], scale),b=x[,"b"])
x.scaled <- x.scaled[,names(x)] #to get the original order of variables
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael. This was very easy to follow. sorry for not including a dummy example. I was also able to use the code to easily not normalize a list of factor variables, not just b!